# Accessing ndarray columns using a custom label

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've just started learning numpy to analyse experimental data and I am trying to give a custom name to a ndarray column so that I can do operations without slicing.

The data I receive is generally a two column .txt file (I'll call it X and Y for the sake of clarity) with a large number of rows corresponding to the measured data. I do operations on those data and generate new columns (I'll call it F(X,Y), G(X,Y,F), ...). I know I can do column-wise operations by slicing ie Data[:,2]=Data[:,1]+Data[:,0], but with a large number of added columns, this becomes tedious. Hence I'm looking for a way to label the columns so that I can refer to a column by its label, and can also label the new columns I generate. So essentially I'm looking for something that'll allow me to directly write F=X+Y (as a substitute for the example above).

Currently, I'm assigning the entire column to a new variable and doing the operations, and then 'hstack'ing it to the data, but I'm unsure of the memory usage here. For example,

```py
X=Data[:,0]
Y=Data[:,1]
F=X+Y
Data=numpy.hstack((Data,F.reshape(n,1)))
```

I've seen the use of structured array and record arrays, but the data I'm dealing with is homogeneous and new columns are being added continuously. Also, I hear Pandas is well suited for what I'm describing, but again, since I'm working with numerical data, I don't find the need to learn a new module, unless it's really needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assigning `X` doesn't use more memory.Calculating F` does, as does using `hstack`.

Comment: _Also, I hear Pandas is well suited for what I'm describing_ That's what I was about to suggest! Your example would look something like `data["F"] = data["X"] + data["Y"]`.

Comment: Looks like you independently came up with the motivation behind pandas. Numpy arrays are fundamentally fixed size buffers.

Comment: @hpaulj I believe this has something to do with copy/deepcopy? In that case, I can initally hstack a number of columns with zero values and then label the columns independently as I've done with X and Y above. That shouldn't make any duplicates that'd cost me memory right?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hehe. As a beginner, one gets all sorts of crazy ideas.

Comment: Indexing like `Data[:,0]` produces a `view` (read `numpy` basics); `X=...` just assigns that to a variable.  A calculation with  arrays makes a new array, the `F=X+Y`.  `hstack` like all  functions using `np.concatenate` makes a new array with values copied from the arguments.  I'd suggest learning the basics of `numpy` (and Python) before worrying too much about fancy column naming or memory use.  Write good basic code first.